# pacman -Syu errors occured, no packages were upgraded

Tags: upgrade, archlinux, pacman-package-manager

Following problem:
After a fresh installation of Blackarch i want to execute
`pacman -Syu`

but after it downloaded all the packages i get the same error for all packages. For example:

`/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/colorize-0.8.1/LICENSE exists in both 'ssrf-proxy and 'yawast'`

Comment: Is your question about the game or the package manager? Read the tag [tag:pacman] description.

Comment: Interesting, I've never noticed that pacman tag description.  I've been watching the tag for about a year now and I rarely see posts about the game, always about the package manager.  I wonder if that tag description changed since then.   The other tag only has 11 messages tagged ever.

Answer (score 0):

This means that two packages claim ownership of the same file.  In reality, they conflict, but the package maintainers haven't noticed and haven't updated MAKEPKG.  You'll need to uninstall one of the packages.  Use `pacman -Qii <package>` to inspect each package.  If one was explicitly installed, then it's safe to remove with `pacman -Rns <package>`